# Script out of range for only one user?

Tags: excel, vba

Background: using VBA for 6 months now running on 64bit machine. Excel 2010 version

Two things. One, and this is the issue, has to do with only one user getting a 'script out of range error' for a line of code. This has run just fine for other users with the same hardware and OS specs. Second, any advice on code optimization is well received.

Line of Code where error occurs:

```
        Set apportion = Application.Workbooks("Apportionment " & year & " template for Granite Block Offshore extensions")
```

The above workbook is where the module is located and assigned to a button so needless to say its open and the activeworkbook when running the macro

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub getEst()

    'Used for inserting values from quarterly estimates paid to shareholders

    Dim xCell As Range, findCell As Range, carryFWDrng1 As Range, carryFWDrng2 As Range
    Dim Q1_est_paid As Range, Q2_est_paid As Range, Q3_est_paid As Range, Q4_est_paid As Range
    Dim tempST$, tempState$, qtr$, year$, pYear$, STest$
    Dim apportion As Workbook, STabbr As Workbook, carryFWD As Workbook
    Dim qrtEst1 As Workbook, qrtEst2 As Workbook, qrtEst3 As Workbook, qrtEst4 As Workbook
    Dim q1Federal&, q2Federal&, q3Federal&, q4Federal&
    Dim t As Date
    Dim STabbrPath$, STabbrFname$, carryFWDpath$, carryFWDfName$
    Dim qrtEst1Path$, qrtEst1Fname$, qrtEst2Path$, qrtEst2Fname$, qrtEst3Path$, qrtEst3Fname$, qrtEst4Path$, qrtEst4Fname$


    'input box to get year for future use
    year = InputBox("Please type in the tax return year", "Tax Return Year", Format(Date - 365, "YYYY"))

    pYear = year - 1

'    t = Now() 'timer to measure sub length

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

    'list file pathways and file names
    STabbrPath = "\\TXLEWFPS02\Departments-ndc\Tax\TAX_DEPT\INCOME TAX\"
    STabbrFname = "States w Abbr.xlsx"
    qrtEst1Path = "\\TXLEWFPS02\Departments-ndc\Tax\TAX_DEPT\INCOME TAX\" & year & " Income Tax\Q1 " & year & "\Blocker & LP Check Requests\"
    qrtEst1Fname = "GBO Q1 " & year & " Estimates Funds Request.xlsx"
    qrtEst2Path = "\\TXLEWFPS02\Departments-ndc\Tax\TAX_DEPT\INCOME TAX\" & year & " Income Tax\Q2 " & year & "\Blocker & LP Check Requests\"
    qrtEst2Fname = "GBO Q2 " & year & " Estimates Funds Request.xlsx"
    qrtEst3Path = "\\TXLEWFPS02\Departments-ndc\Tax\TAX_DEPT\INCOME TAX\" & year & " Income Tax\Q3 " & year & "\Blocker & LP Check Requests\"
    qrtEst3Fname = "GBO Q3 " & year & " Estimates Funds Request.xlsx"
    qrtEst4Path = "\\TXLEWFPS02\Departments-ndc\Tax\TAX_DEPT\INCOME TAX\" & year & " Income Tax\Q4 " & year & "\Blocker & LP Check Requests\"
    qrtEst4Fname = "GBO Q4 " & year & " Estimates Funds Request.xlsx"
    carryFWDpath = "\\TXLEWFPS02\Departments-ndc\Tax\TAX_DEPT\INCOME TAX\Blocker Returns\" & pYear & "\Granite Block Offshore\"
    carryFWDfName = "Granite Block Offshore income tax recap " & pYear & ".xlsx"

    'open files
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=STabbrPath & STabbrFname
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=qrtEst1Path & qrtEst1Fname
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=qrtEst2Path & qrtEst2Fname
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=qrtEst3Path & qrtEst3Fname
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=qrtEst4Path & qrtEst4Fname
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=carryFWDpath & carryFWDfName


    Set apportion = Application.Workbooks("Apportionment " & year & " template for Granite Block Offshore extensions")
    Set STabbr = Application.Workbooks("States w Abbr")
    Set carryFWD = Application.Workbooks("Granite Block Offshore income tax recap " & pYear)
    Set qrtEst1 = Application.Workbooks("GBO Q1 " & year & " Estimates Funds Request")
    Set qrtEst2 = Application.Workbooks("GBO Q2 " & year & " Estimates Funds Request")
    Set qrtEst3 = Application.Workbooks("GBO Q3 " & year & " Estimates Funds Request")
    Set qrtEst4 = Application.Workbooks("GBO Q4 " & year & " Estimates Funds Request")


    Set Q1_est_paid = Application.Workbooks("Apportionment " & year & " template for Granite Block Offshore extensions") _
    .Worksheets("Granite Block Offshore").Range("F58:DB58")
    Set Q2_est_paid = Application.Workbooks("Apportionment " & year & " template for Granite Block Offshore extensions") _
    .Worksheets("Granite Block Offshore").Range("F60:DB60")
    Set Q3_est_paid = Application.Workbooks("Apportionment " & year & " template for Granite Block Offshore extensions") _
    .Worksheets("Granite Block Offshore").Range("F62:DB62")
    Set Q4_est_paid = Application.Workbooks("Apportionment " & year & " template for Granite Block Offshore extensions") _
    .Worksheets("Granite Block Offshore").Range("F64:DB64")
    Set carryFWDrng1 = Application.Workbooks("Apportionment " & year & " template for Granite Block Offshore extensions") _
    .Worksheets("Granite Block Offshore").Range("F57:DB57")
    Set carryFWDrng2 = Application.Workbooks("Granite Block Offshore income tax recap " & pYear) _
    .Worksheets("Granite Block Offshore").Range("K9:K59")

    apportion.Activate

'For loop to move through each cell in carryFWD range
    For Each xCell In carryFWDrng1
        If xCell.Offset(-56, 0).Value = "" Then
            'do nothing
        Else:   tempST = xCell.Offset(-56, 0).Value
                STabbr.Activate 'activate States w Abbr file to find full state name
                Set findCell = Range("B1:B51").Find(what:=tempST, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Range("B1")) 'search ST range and find tempST var
                    If findCell Is Nothing Then
                    'do nothing
                    Else: tempState = findCell.Offset(0, -1).Value 'populate tempState var
                    End If
                Set findCell = Nothing 'clear findcell in memory
                    carryFWD.Activate 'activate GBO tax recap file
                Set findCell = Range("A9:A59").Find(what:=tempState, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Range("A9")) 'search State range and find tempState var
                    If findCell Is Nothing Then
                    STest = "0"
                    Else: STest = findCell.Offset(0, 10).Value
                    End If
                Set findCell = Nothing 'clear findcell in memory
                apportion.Activate 'activate apportion file
                    xCell.Value = STest
        End If
    Next xCell

    apportion.Activate

'For loop to move through each cell in Q1 range
    For Each xCell In Q1_est_paid
        If xCell.Offset(-57, 0).Value = "" Then
            'do nothing
        Else:   tempST = xCell.Offset(-57, 0).Value
                STabbr.Activate 'activate States w Abbr file to find full state name
                Set findCell = Range("B1:B51").Find(what:=tempST, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Range("B1")) 'search ST range and find tempST var
                    If findCell Is Nothing Then
                    'do nothing
                    Else: tempState = findCell.Offset(0, -1).Value 'populate tempState var
                    End If
                Set findCell = Nothing 'clear findcell in memory
                    qrtEst1.Activate 'activate Q1 payment file
                Set findCell = Range("A7:A60").Find(what:=tempState, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Range("A7")) 'search State range and find tempState var
                    If findCell Is Nothing Then
                    STest = "0"
                    Else: STest = findCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    End If
                Set findCell = Nothing 'clear findcell in memory
                apportion.Activate 'activate apportion file
                    xCell.Value = STest
        End If
    Next xCell

    qrtEst1.Activate 'get Federal est in Q1
    q1Federal = qrtEst1.Worksheets("GBO").Range("B5")
    apportion.Activate
    apportion.Worksheets("Granite Block Offshore").Range("D58").Value = q1Federal

'For loop to move through each cell in Q2 range
    For Each xCell In Q2_est_paid
        If xCell.Offset(-59, 0).Value = "" Then
            'do nothing
        Else:   tempST = xCell.Offset(-59, 0).Value
                STabbr.Activate 'activate States w Abbr file to find full state name
                Set findCell = Range("B1:B51").Find(what:=tempST, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Range("B1")) 'search ST range and find tempST var
                    If findCell Is Nothing Then
                    'do nothing
                    Else: tempState = findCell.Offset(0, -1).Value 'populate tempState var
                    End If
                Set findCell = Nothing 'clear findcell in memory
                    qrtEst2.Activate 'activate Q2 payment file
                Set findCell = Range("A7:A60").Find(what:=tempState, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Range("A7")) 'search State range and find tempState var
                    If findCell Is Nothing Then
                    STest = "0"
                    Else: STest = findCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    End If
                Set findCell = Nothing 'clear findcell in memory
                apportion.Activate 'active apportion file
                    xCell.Value = STest
        End If
    Next xCell

    qrtEst2.Activate 'get Federal est in Q2
    q2Federal = qrtEst2.Worksheets("GBO").Range("B5")
    apportion.Activate
    apportion.Worksheets("Granite Block Offshore").Range("D60").Value = q2Federal

'For loop to move through each cell in Q3 range
    For Each xCell In Q3_est_paid
        If xCell.Offset(-61, 0).Value = "" Then
            'do nothing
        Else:   tempST = xCell.Offset(-61, 0).Value
                STabbr.Activate 'activate States w Abbr file to find full state name
                Set findCell = Range("B1:B51").Find(what:=tempST, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Range("B1")) 'search ST range and find tempST var
                    If findCell Is Nothing Then
                    'do nothing
                    Else: tempState = findCell.Offset(0, -1).Value 'populate tempState var
                    End If
                Set findCell = Nothing 'clear findcell in memory
                    qrtEst3.Activate 'activate Q3 payment file
                Set findCell = Range("A7:A60").Find(what:=tempState, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Range("A7")) 'search State range and find tempState var
                    If findCell Is Nothing Then
                    STest = "0"
                    Else: STest = findCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    End If
                Set findCell = Nothing 'clear findcell in memory
                apportion.Activate 'active apportion file
                    xCell.Value = STest
        End If
    Next xCell

    qrtEst3.Activate 'get Federal est in Q3
    q3Federal = qrtEst3.Worksheets("GBO").Range("B5")
    apportion.Activate
    apportion.Worksheets("Granite Block Offshore").Range("D62").Value = q3Federal

'For loop to move through each cell in Q4 range
    For Each xCell In Q4_est_paid
        If xCell.Offset(-63, 0).Value = "" Then
            'do nothing
        Else:   tempST = xCell.Offset(-63, 0).Value
                STabbr.Activate 'activate States w Abbr file to find full state name
                Set findCell = Range("B1:B51").Find(what:=tempST, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Range("B1")) 'search ST range and find tempST var
                    If findCell Is Nothing Then
                    'do nothing
                    Else: tempState = findCell.Offset(0, -1).Value 'populate tempState var
                    End If
                Set findCell = Nothing 'clear findcell in memory
                    qrtEst4.Activate 'activate Q3 payment file
                Set findCell = Range("A7:A60").Find(what:=tempState, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Range("A7")) 'search State range and find tempState var
                    If findCell Is Nothing Then
                    STest = "0"
                    Else: STest = findCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    End If
                Set findCell = Nothing 'clear findcell in memory
                apportion.Activate 'active apportion file
                    xCell.Value = STest
        End If
    Next xCell

    qrtEst4.Activate 'get Federal est in Q4
    q4Federal = qrtEst4.Worksheets("GBO").Range("B5")

    apportion.Activate
    apportion.Worksheets("Granite Block Offshore").Range("D64").Value = q4Federal

    Range("DK57").Value = "Carry FWD source file pathway"
    Range("DK58").Value = "Q1 source file pathway"
    Range("DK60").Value = "Q2 source file pathway"
    Range("DK62").Value = "Q3 source file pathway"
    Range("DK64").Value = "Q4 source file pathway"
    Range("DL57").Value = carryFWDpath & carryFWDfName
    Range("DL58").Value = qrtEst1Path & qrtEst1Fname
    Range("DL60").Value = qrtEst2Path & qrtEst2Fname
    Range("DL62").Value = qrtEst3Path & qrtEst3Fname
    Range("DL64").Value = qrtEst4Path & qrtEst4Fname

    STabbr.Close savechanges:=False
    carryFWD.Close savechanges:=False
    qrtEst1.Close savechanges:=False
    qrtEst2.Close savechanges:=False
    qrtEst3.Close savechanges:=False
    qrtEst4.Close savechanges:=False

    Set Q1_est_paid = Nothing
    Set Q2_est_paid = Nothing
    Set Q3_est_paid = Nothing
    Set Q4_est_paid = Nothing
    Set qrtEst1 = Nothing
    Set qrtEst2 = Nothing
    Set qrtEst3 = Nothing
    Set qrtEst4 = Nothing
    Set STabbr = Nothing
    Set apportion = Nothing
    Set carryFWD = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True

'MsgBox ("Macro duration : " & Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss")) 'timer results

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the extension:

```
Set apportion = Application.Workbooks("Apportionment " & year & " template for Granite Block Offshore extensions.xls")
```

or `.xlsm` if macro'ed. User might have file extension hidden.

Also you might not want to show your true path but using \mypath\ instead from publishing it